# How to downgrade glibc-common from 2.17-260.el7 to 2.17-222.el7

Tags: rhel, software-installation, glibc

I am trying to install `gcc` on my `RHEL 7.6 Beta` workstation. At the moment, I am doing it using the command `yum install gcc`, but I keep receiving this error:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.17-222.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.17-222.el7
           Installed: glibc-common-2.17-260.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.6)
....
....
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-222.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
           glibc-common = 2.17-222.el7
```

Although the required package `glibc-2.17-222.el7.i686` is available on `rhel-7-server-e4s-rpms repo`, I am not able to install it!

Comment: Why would you want to downgrade your `glibc` installation?  Is `glibc-2.17-260.el7.i686` installed?

Comment: Hi Andrew. The reason to downgrade this package is because `gcc` requires this specific version as you can see in the output above.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find the solution. After learning a little me more about the platform, the command required to downgrade the `glibc` package is:

`yum -y downgrade glibc glibc-common`

In my case, it downgraded `glibc` from `2.17-260.el7` to `2.17-222.el7`.

This method can be apply to any package as long it exists in your repositories. You can double check the different versions for a specific package with the command:

`yum list --showduplicates <package_name>`

Comment: I agree with upstaris. and in order to avoid errors ,Here is my code yum -y --skip-broken downgrade glibc glibc-common